# Jquery toggle not closing row when new one is opened

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem when trying to get jquery to close an open row in a table while opening another.   I am trying to use toggle() to no avail and I know I am just missing something.   Here is my html:

```
<table class="ProcTable" rules="all" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>   
      <tr class="proctablerow">
         <th>Recently Issued Procedures</th>         
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Admin</td>
         <td>User Name #1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Reader</td>
         <td>User Name #2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Reader</td>
         <td>User Name #3</td>
      </tr> 
      </tbody>    
</table>
<table class="ProcTable" rules="all" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>   
      <tr class="proctablerow">
         <th>Recently Viewed Procedures</th>         
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Admin</td>
         <td>User Name #1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Reader</td>
         <td>User Name #2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Reader</td>
         <td>User Name #3</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>      
      </table>
      <table class="ProcTable" rules="all" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>   
      <tr class="proctablerow">
         <th>Bookmarked Procedures</th>         
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Admin</td>
         <td>User Name #1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Reader</td>
         <td>User Name #2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>Reader</td>
         <td>User Name #3</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>      
      </table>

      </table>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#accordion").accordion( { active: false, collapsible: true });
    $(".ProcTable").accordion( { active: false, collapsible: true, autoHeight: false });  

    $('table.ProcTable tr.proctablerow th') .click(
    function() {
        $(this) .parents('table.ProcTable') .children('tbody') .toggle();
    });

});
```

Can someone help me figure out how to close one row while opening another row (accordion style).  Thanks!

Comment: seems like an odd markup/way to use an accordion to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('table.ProcTable tr.proctablerow th').on('click', function() {
    var elm = $(this).parents('table.ProcTable').children('tbody');
    $('table.ProcTable').children('tbody').not(elm).hide();
    elm.toggle();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TPXG6/2/)